# $A$ is a subset of $B$ if and only if $P(A) \subset P(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I had to prove the following for a trial calculus exam:

$A\subset B$ if and only if $P(A) \subset P(B)$ where $P(A)$ is the set of all subsets of $A$.

Can someone tell me if my approach is correct and please give the correct proof otherwise?

$PROOF$:

$\Big(\Longrightarrow\Big)$ assume $A\subset B$ is true. Then $\forall$ $a\in A$, $a\in B$

Then for $\forall$ A, the elements $a_1, a_2,$ ... , $a_n$ in A are also in B.

Hence $P(A)\subset P(B)$

$\Big(\Longleftarrow\Big) $ assume $P(A) \subset P(B)$ is true. We prove this by contradiction so assume $A\not\subset B$

Then there is a set $A$ with an element $a$ in it, $a\notin$ B.

Hence $P(A) \not\subset P(B)$

But we assumed $P(A) = P(B)$ is true.

We reached a contradiction.

Hence if $P(A) = P(B)$ then $A\subset B$.

---

I proved it both sides now, please improve me if I did something wrong :-)

Comment: What do you mean with $\forall A$. When you take any $A\subset B$ you can not change $A$ anymore. It was chosen.

Comment: Your $\to$ proof assumes $A$ is finite.  Your $\leftarrow$ proof does not explain why $P(A)\neq P(B)$; plus what you need to contradict is not $P(A)=P(B)$ but $P(A)\subset P(B)$.

Comment: Note that this question (as a question) has been asked before on the site. You may want to post an answer, instead of a new question, and then see what sort of feedback you're getting (or compare this to previously given answers at first).

Comment: For the $\Rightarrow$ direction you only need the transitivity of the subset relation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither direction seems to be valid. Here is the correct approach.

$(\Rightarrow)$  Assume $A \subseteq B$.  Then for any $C \in P(A)$, we have $C \subseteq A \subseteq B$.  Hence, $C \in P(B)$.

$(\Leftarrow)$  Assume $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$.   Since $A \in P(A)$, $A \in P(B)$, meaning $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: thank you, can you please explain to me why $C\in P(A)$, then $C\subset A$?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it :-), thank you

Answer (score 5):

$(\Rightarrow)$ Given any $x\in P(A)$ then $x\subset A$. So, by hypothesis, $x\subset B$ and so $x\in P(B)$.

The counter part is easier, as cited by @Asaf, below.

Comment: The counterpart is easier. $A\in\mathcal P(A)\subseteq\mathcal P(B)$ so $A\subseteq B$ by definition.

Comment: @Sigur why is it so that if $x\in P(A)$, then $x\subset A$ ?

Comment: @SjoerdSmaal, the elements of the power set of $A$, denoted by $P(A)$, are all the subsets of $A$ (including the empty set and the total set $A$). What is the definition of $P(A)$ for you? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

Comment: @Sigur The same as yours :-), but what I don't get is, if you pick a subset $x$ out of $P(A)$, then the subset $x$ is a subset of a subset $A$?

Comment: For example, if $A=\{a,b,c\}$ then $P(A)=\{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$. Then $\{a\}\in P(A)$ (not $\{a\}\subset P(A)$). Also $\{\{a\}\}\subset P(A)$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $A\in P(A)$. So you don't need proof by contradiction for the second part.

The first part, by enumerating elements as you have, assumes that there are finitely many $a_i$. That's sloppy notation.

Rather, assume $A\subseteq B$.

If $X\in P(A)$, then $X\subseteq A$, hence $$\forall x\in X: x\in A$$ But $x\in A\implies x\in B$. So we conclude: $$\forall x\in X:x\in B$$ This means that $X\subseteq B$, and hence $X\in P(B)$. So we have shown that if $X\in P(A)$ then $X\in P(B)$, therefore $P(A)\subseteq P(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically correct, but you may be asked to be more precise. You shouldn't use the fact that $a\in A$ is not in $B$ to say $P(A)$ isn't equal to $P(B)$. Instead, say that $P(A)$ isn't contained in $P(B)$.